# Spray-json: [error] Referring to non-existent class spray.json.package$

Tags: scala, scala.js, spray-json

I am following [this](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes). I have defined JsonFormat for my custom case class as:

```
object RecipeJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val recipeFormat = jsonFormat4(Recipe.apply)
}
```

...and then used it as following in same file:

```
  import RecipeJsonProtocol._
  def postRecipe(recipe: Recipe): Callback = {
    val json = recipe.toJson.toString()
    Ajax.post(url = "....", data = json).onComplete {
      case Success(xhr) => println("....")
      case Failure(t) => println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
    }

    Callback.empty
  }
```

But this is throwing error as:

```
[error] Referring to non-existent class spray.json.package$
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you read https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/linking-errors.html ? In particular "Depending on a JVM library instead of a JS library" ?

Comment: So I changed dependency to "com.typesafe.akka" %%% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.2.4". Earlier I was having %%. But now sbt update itself fails. 'Extracting structure failed, reason: not ok build status'